# Getting a NotFoundHttpException() Error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I just have a very simple product category creation form in laravel , like so:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/category/create')) }}
          <p>
            {{ Form::label('name') }}
            {{ Form::text('name') }}
          </p>
          {{ Form::submit('Create Category' , array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
          {{ Form::close() }}
```

For the create method i have the following code:

```
  public function postCreate() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all() , Category::$rules);

    if($validator->passes()) {
      $category = new Category;
      $category->name = Input::get('name');
      $category->save();

      return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
         ->with('message' , 'Category created');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
      ->with('message' , 'something went wrong')
      ->withError($validator)
      ->withInput();

  }
```

Now when i click on the submit button, i get the following error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomm\bootstrap\compiled.php
>
> if (!is_null($route)) {
>               return $route->bind($request);
>           }
>           $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);
>           if (count($others) > 0) {
>               return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
>           }
>           throw new NotFoundHttpException();
>       }
>       protected function checkForAlternateVerbs($request)

You can see the error more visvually **[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKfQF.jpg)**.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Laravel can't find the routes when you redirect the form.

Comment: can you give me the code of routes where you are sending the data?

Comment: show your routes.php?

Comment: my routes.php file looks like so http://chopapp.com/#vgz54ia4 .(wait 5 secs for the code to load)

Comment: Can you insert the `return 'true';` after $validator->passes(); If it's returning the word TRUE?

Comment: @aldrin27 u mean before the redirect statement ?

Comment: the uri in the form opening should be    {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/categories/create')) }}

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen not working still

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/category/create')) }}
      <p>
        {{ Form::label('name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
      </p>
      {{ Form::submit('Create Category' , array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
      {{ Form::close() }}
```

try this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'post.homes')) }}
      <p>
        {{ Form::label('name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name') }}
      </p>
      {{ Form::submit('Create Category' , array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
      {{ Form::close() }}
```

## In routes.php:

```
Route::post('aboutus', array('as' => 'post.homes', 'uses' => 'HomeController@postContactUs'));
```